# White space between body and div

Tags: html, css

I have been looking everywhere for a solution to my problem, but nothing seems to work. It always bugged me that the top of my website always had a gap on the top and all the answers to the problem did nothing. I inspected the website in firefox and found that there was a whitespace between the body and first div (I tried putting the code on the same row but that did nothing). Any Idea on how to remove the whitespace? (I can remove it in inspect on firefox and it goes away there)[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
/* CSS Document */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #111111;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: verdana;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.menubar {
  left: 100;
}

.ulmenubar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ulmenubar a {
  float: left;
}

.space {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rightside {
  float: right;
}

.ulmenubar a {
  display: block;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ulmenubar a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #181818;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#contact {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#cover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
  <ul class="ulmenubar">
    <div class="rightside">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#vids">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="space"><video id="background-video" autoplay="" loop="" muted=""><source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="vids"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/xT8qBoDhee6aWOhLqw/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611a86749120009311d9c18651c96962c8e7e27def2&amp;rid=giphy.gif&amp;ct=g" alt="Sea" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a onclick="openWin()"><img src="https://media4.giphy.com/media/UxTZDNv0Zej4s/giphy.gif?cid=790b76118b066a194adc23988667623a5aea3c7b55f3c44b&amp;rid=giphy.gif&amp;ct=g" alt="Forest" style="width:100%"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://media4.giphy.com/media/l41lQIclE3lItAlfq/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47mgmmt0kas0kp9zc0435gcanw878chwmk129z9uhf&amp;rid=giphy.gif&amp;ct=g" alt="Sky" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add site link? Or more code presentation. Part of code which you added in question works fine https://codepen.io/rachkovartem/pen/OJoVgqZ

Comment: Your snippet here doesn't appear to reproduce the problem. (But the code here starts with the div, and the issue appears to be whitespace between the body and that div, so that is probably due to the snippet structure here.) And that is says `whitespace` there in the dev tools, but then that whitespace is suddenly supposed to have "dimensions", is also a bit weird. Text nodes don't really have dimensions, only element nodes do.

Comment: What should I do? replacing the the code there does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of trying, I figured out what the problem was. This may not be the case but when I went into the HTML file on text edit, I saw two `<body>` on the top, I deleted one and also deleted the space between `<head>` and `<body>`. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

Add this to your CSS

Comment: The screenshot shows the padding of the text node already being 0, though.

Comment: That does not work and it is also what the other ones said todp